# Resend old password to user's email in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, passwords, send

On a blog of mine, a user asked me if I could tell him his password from that account, which happens to be the same password he used on multiple accounts, on an email which was deactived - the point is he needs that specific password.

Since the only option in the Wordpress Dashboard is to change the password, I had to look in phpmyadmin, under wp_users table at his password. The things is, the password is encrypted unde wordpress's unique encoding hash, phpass I believe, since it starts with $P$B. If it was 2008 again and wordpress would've used MD5 to enconde password in sql tables, it would have been easier.

From my knowledge I know that phpass pasword can't be decrypted, naturally, since it's a one-way encryption method. The only way would be to bruteforce it, which is out of the question.

And then, I thought about resending the user an e-mail containing the password. I searched the plugins page and found one named: 'Re-send Welcome e-mail' which still resets it eventualy.
I think that this method is plausable, because, if I change the password in the wp_users table with another one encoded in phpass, he can login with the new one, so Wordpress somehow verifies it by encoding or decoding it, or by enconding it and comparing the hash of the password entered with the one already present in the wp_users table, under that user's row.

Is there a plugin available or a turn-around to this situations? I overthinked the whole situation and now I'm out of solutions which are in my league of knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea of hashing is that you can't read the password. So no, you can't resend or retrieve the password from a hashed string besides trying bruteforce.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function